# NodeJS web server lagging

Tags: node.js, sqlite, socket.io

After 1-2 min. running web server on raspberry pi, i get lag. I use nodeJS, socket.io and sqlite database. I suspect this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
setInterval(function(){
fs.readFile('/sys/bus/w1/devices/'+ tempId +'/w1_slave', function(error, buffer){
  // Read data from file (using fast node ASCII encoding).
  var data = buffer.toString('ascii').split(" "); // Split by space
  // Extract temperature from string and divide by 1000 to give celsius
  var temp  = parseFloat(data[data.length-1].split("=")[1])/1000.0;
  // Round to one decimal place
  temp = Math.round(temp * 10) / 10;
  // Add date/time to temperature
    var data = {
        temp_irasai:[{
        laikas: Date.now()+10800000,
        laipsnis: temp
        }]};
    socket.emit('realtime', data);
    var statement = db.prepare("INSERT INTO temp_irasai VALUES (?, ?)");
    statement.run(data.temp_irasai[0].laikas, data.temp_irasai[0].laipsnis);
    statement.finalize();   
});
}, 8000);
});
```

then i comment this line:

```
var statement = db.prepare("INSERT INTO temp_irasai VALUES (?, ?)");
statement.run(data.temp_irasai[0].laikas, data.temp_irasai[0].laipsnis);
statement.finalize();
```

Lag gone, so that's wrong with this function.

But its not working:

```
db.run("BEGIN TRANSACTION;");
var statement = db.prepare("INSERT INTO temp_irasai VALUES (?, ?);");
statement.run(data.temp_irasai[0].laikas, data.temp_irasai[0].laipsnis);
statement.finalize();   
db.run("commit;");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extremely common problem in sqlite that has been answered in the FAQ. Take a look at https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19 for more details. As quoted:

> Actually, SQLite will easily do 50,000 or more INSERT statements per second on an average desktop computer. But it will only do a few
>   dozen transactions per second. Transaction speed is limited by the
>   rotational speed of your disk drive. A transaction normally requires
>   two complete rotations of the disk platter, which on a 7200RPM disk
>   drive limits you to about 60 transactions per second.
>
> Transaction speed is limited by disk drive speed because (by default) SQLite actually waits until the data really is safely stored
>   on the disk surface before the transaction is complete. That way, if
>   you suddenly lose power or if your OS crashes, your data is still
>   safe. For details, read about atomic commit in SQLite..
>
> By default, each INSERT statement is its own transaction. But if you surround multiple INSERT statements with BEGIN...COMMIT then all
>   the inserts are grouped into a single transaction. The time needed to
>   commit the transaction is amortized over all the enclosed insert
>   statements and so the time per insert statement is greatly reduced.

EDIT:

To fix it, what you want to do is to execute "BEGIN" before and "COMMIT" after all of the insert statements are executed.

Comment: But i cant understand how fix that.

Comment: If you are unable to follow the instructions, perhaps you might want to take a closer look at SQL :)

Comment: but its still lagging